# How to instantiate a form in classes?

Tags: c#

**I need to use these components of class "Camera" in the Form, but the following error occurs:**

> System.TypeInitializationException: 'The type initializer for
>   'VideoRecognition.NeorisForm' threw an exception.'

**NeorisForm.css**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using VideoRecognition.FRAMEWORKS.AForge.Camera;

namespace VideoRecognition
{
    public partial class NeorisForm : Form
    {

        private static Camera AForgeCamera = new Camera();

        public NeorisForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            AForgeCamera.BuscarDispositivos();
        }



        private void NeorisForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        }

        private void btn_IniciarCamera_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AForgeCamera.LigarCamera();
        }

        private void btn_PararVideo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AForgeCamera.DesligarCamera();
        }
    }
}
```

**Camera.css**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using AForge.Video.DirectShow;
using AForge.Video;
using System.Drawing;

namespace VideoRecognition.FRAMEWORKS.AForge.Camera
{
    public class Camera
    {
        private FilterInfoCollection DispositivosCamera;
        private VideoCaptureDevice cameras;

        private static NeorisForm formPrincipal = new NeorisForm();

        public void LigarCamera() {
            cameras = new VideoCaptureDevice(DispositivosCamera[formPrincipal.comboBox_ListaDispositivos.SelectedIndex].MonikerString);
            cameras.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(Cameras_NovosFrames);
            cameras.Start();
        }

        public void DesligarCamera() {
            cameras.SignalToStop();
        }

        public void BuscarDispositivos() {
            DispositivosCamera = new FilterInfoCollection(FilterCategory.VideoInputDevice);

            foreach (FilterInfo DispositivosCamerasEncontrados in DispositivosCamera)
            {
                formPrincipal.comboBox_ListaDispositivos.Items.Add(DispositivosCamerasEncontrados.Name);
            }

            formPrincipal.comboBox_ListaDispositivos.SelectedIndex = 0;
        }

        private void Cameras_NovosFrames(object sender, NewFrameEventArgs eventargs)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)eventargs.Frame.Clone();
            formPrincipal.pictureBox_cameraPlayer.Image = bitmap;
        } 

    }
}
```

Comment: looks like there is a *circular reference* present

Comment: @Rahul What should I do?

Comment: `private static NeorisForm formPrincipal = new NeorisForm();` tries to create a new form. Instead, pass the original form to the `Camera` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the result I think you are expecting, create a constructor on the Camera class that takes a NeorisForm, then pass a reference to the form as you create the Camera.  Something like this..

On the NeorisForm class, change the camera declaration to:

```
private static Camera AForgeCamera;
```

On the Camera class, change the NeorisForm declaration to this:

```
private static NeorisForm formPrincipal;
```

and add a Camera Constructor like this:

```
public Camera(NeorisForm form)
{
    formPrincipal = form;
}
```

Then instantiate the Camera in the NeorisForm constructor like this:

```
public NeorisForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    AForgeCamera = new Camera(this);
    AForgeCamera.BuscarDispositivos();
}
```

I have to admit that the use of static variables like that, essentially binding these two classes together, makes me a little nervous (and reduces the utility of the classes) but I'll assume you've got some unique requirements that necessitate that type of relationship.

Good luck!